# Auto Slash for user input in Python

Tags: python

I've just started learning to code in Python and am getting started by writing a user details program.

I've got it working correctly to as how it should but I am stuck on how I can get a slash '/' to appear after the user enters in their first day of their date of birth. So when the user enters in 05051990. I want the interface to automatically show a slash '/' after the first 5 and then for the month before the year.

```
import os   
import time
def main():
    while True:
        username = input ("Enter your Username: ")
        password = input ("Enter your Password: ")
        dateofbirth = input ("Enter your Date of Birth: ")

        if username == 'james' and password == 'test' or 'James' and password == 'Test' and dateofbirth == '05/05/1990':
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Login successful!") 
            logged()

        else:
            print("Incorrect login details")

def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome!")

main()
```

[image: interface photo]

Comment: Opinion corner: as soon as you require more granulated control over user input than what input() can natively provide, that's the time to migrate to a GUI.

Comment: your code logic is flawed btw `password == 'test' or 'James'`

Comment: or use getch to read char by char at a lower level

Comment: I wanted to make it so if the user entered in details it would be case sensitive, should i change the 'or' to 'and'?

Comment: put the two `and` statements into brackets and add another `username==` before the second `'James'`